# Start Apache even without a /var/log/apache2 directory

Tags: apache, logging

I've a standard Apache Config. Log files are stored under /var/log/apache2.
When the directory /var/log/apache2 exist apache can't start. Shown Errors:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1
AH00014: Configuration check failed
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I don't want to create a tmpfs, folder or whatever under /var/log/apache2 when the path is missing

**Can I tell apache to ignore this error?** Or Can I tell apache to take a fallback Log File Path like /tmp?

Comment: You are much better off keeping logging in tact, and not overly messing with Apache's configuration. There will come a time, when you will need those logs to help debug a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796943/accidentally-deleted-var-log-apache2-and-now-cant-restart-apache

Comment: Normally the logging directory would be available. but in some case (when the log directory could not be mounted) the log dir would not be available. even in this case I want to have a started apache.

Comment: You can look at the APACHE_LOG_DIR in envvars: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-apache-on-an-ubuntu-vps